# оповещение о подключении к сети

Tags: c++, linux, c

Есть ли в линукс какое нибудь оповещение, когда подключаешься к сети? Это для программирования. Я хочу отслеживать интерфейс например, но не знаю какой адрес будет у интерфейса. Когда я подключаюсь к wifi например, то я должен как то узнать что подлючился к сети и мне выдался адрес, чтобы я мог использовать этот адрес.

Comment: [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2916632/4607234) и [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15905276/4607234) посмотрите

Comment: *Помимо того что мне надо знать как это делается в линукс, я хочу знать также как это делается в windows.* — так задайте соответствющий вопрос.